# Invoking a Cached Delegate when T is unknown

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates

So, I am working in a ORM-like piece of code that needs to instantiate and populate objects without knowing them ahead of time, using reflection SetValue/GetValue and attributes. That works, but the performance is horrible, since I need to create new instances and then iterate their properties for each new "row", and the object might have nested objects that need to be created/populated too.

So I tried using and caching delegates of the getters/setters, but I found some problems. Please see this example code for just the getters, I assume the setters would be even worse (sorry for the VB code lol):

```
Public Class CommonDTO 
'actual objects
  Public Property UID As String
  Public Property CreateDate As DateTime
End Class

Public Class torm
  Private flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public
  Private common As Type = GetType(CommonDTO)
  'List for holding all the supported types, inside it contains many dictionaries holding the actual delegates
  Public listCacheGet As New ConditionalWeakTable(Of Type, Dictionary(Of String, [Delegate]))
  Private commonUID As PropertyInfo = Common.GetProperty("UID", flags)
  Private commonCreateDate As PropertyInfo = Common.GetProperty("CreateDate", flags)
  'Create the delegates for the get/set of each property. This is a royal PITA btw
  Public getcommonUID As Func(Of CommonDTO, String) = CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of CommonDTO, String)),
                                                                    commonUID.GetGetMethod(nonPublic:=True)), Func(Of CommonDTO, String))
  Public setcommonUID As Action(Of CommonDTO, String) = CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of CommonDTO, String)),
                                                                        commonUID.GetSetMethod()), Action(Of CommonDTO, String))
  Public getcommonCreateDate As Func(Of CommonDTO, DateTime) = CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of CommonDTO, DateTime)),
                                                           commonCreateDate.GetGetMethod(nonPublic:=True)), Func(Of CommonDTO, DateTime))
  Public setcommonCreateDate As Action(Of CommonDTO, DateTime) = CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of CommonDTO, DateTime)),
                                                                        commonCreateDate.GetSetMethod()), Action(Of CommonDTO, DateTime))

Public Sub New()
    Dim listCommonDTOGet As New Dictionary(Of String, [Delegate])
    'Fill the lists
    listCommonDTOGet.Add("UID", getcommonUID)
    listCommonDTOGet.Add("CreateDate", getcommonCreateDate)

    listCacheGet.Add(common, listCommonDTOGet)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Test
Public Sub test(tdto as type)
    Dim orm As New torm
    Dim tempDTO = Activator.CreateInstance(tdto)
    Dim dictCache As IDictionary = Nothing

    'obtain the dictionary for the type that we are using
    orm.listCacheGet.TryGetValue(tdto, dictCache)

    '...but here is the problem. I don't know the exact type of the delegate 
    'contained within. I don't know how to instantiate it on its actual
    'Func/Action definition (because this procedure doesn't know it, 
    'and I think that T wouldn't work either, because the callers 
    'wouldn't know the actual Func/Action definition either, 
    'so I have only managed to create it as Object or [Delegate] 
    Dim getv as [Delegate] = dictCache.Item("UID")

    '...so getv ends up being an object that actually has the cached 
    'delegate and I have no idea how to invoke.
    'Well, I CAN do this, but it's even slower than using 
    'SetValue/GetValue!!
    Console.Writeline(getv.DynamicInvoke(tempDTO))

    'and of course, the direct calling is super fast
    Console.Writeline(orm.getcommonUID(tempDTO))
End Sub
End Class
```

What am I missing here? I got the feeling it's something very basic that I'm overlooking, so I would appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "sorry for the VB code lol" <- what does that mean?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer that a lot of people hates VB for one reason or another. And my code is ugly on top of that ;)

Comment: Even if you don't know the `T`, as long as something passes in a type, you can instantiate a generic type on it at runtime.  e.g. `Dim myGeneric = GetType(GenericType(Of ))` (intentionally blank after the `Of`) then `Dim mySpecific = myGeneric.MakeGenericType(specificType)`.  I'm not sure if that will help you.  There are some other cool things you can do with setting up getter/setter delegates if the client code knows the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks way too complicated. If you have place (class torn) where you explictly know the type of object, you can directcast them it in there. And keep universal delegate types.

Try to use setters/getters like this to avoid type/dependency in your invocation code

```
Public Delegate Function GetStringDelegate(Instance As Object) As String
Public Delegate Sub SetStringDelegate(Instance As Object, Value As String)

Public getCommonDTOUID As GetStringDelegate = Function(Instance) DirectCast(Instance, CommonDTO).UID
Public setCommonDTOUID As SetStringDelegate = Sub(Instance, Value) DirectCast(Instance, CommonDTO).UID = Value
```

I expect there to be list of TypeName => List of getters/setters collection informed about type object.

You can go with universal Object delegate as well:

```
Public Delegate Function GetDelegate(Instance As Object) As Object
Public Delegate Sub SetDelegate(Instance As Object, Value As Object)

Public getCommonDTOUID As GetDelegate = Function(Instance) DirectCast(Instance, CommonDTO).UID
Public setCommonDTOUID As SetDelegate = Sub(Instance, Value) DirectCast(Instance, CommonDTO).UID = CStr(Value)
```

That depends of your invocation needs. String invocation would look something like this

```
Dim Value As String = DirectCast(dictCache.Item("UID"), GetStringDelegate)(tdto)
```

Comment: Your solution is indeed way simpler to implement... sadly even with delegates my real code is still incredibly slow, so I guess it wasn't the get/set usage. Your answer was correct for my question tho. Thanks.

Comment: Theese delegates should be as fast as you can reach (even compared to dynamically generated assembly). Try to use bunch of StopWatch around parts of your code to find out slow part of the code. With aggregating time from all iterations. It might be slowing down somewhere else (listCacheGet.TryGetValue, dictCache.item)

Comment: I was doing that as I accepted your answer. It turns out that using the delegates did improve about 10% the general call, but the problem lies in a SSIS DataReader that takes an insane amount of time reading each field. I'm looking into it right now.